# Node ExpressJS - .get rewritten as .route with connect-ensure-login middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

so I have a route written with `app.route`:

```
app.route('/word/:id')
    .get(word.getWord)
    .put(word.updateWord)
    .delete(word.deleteWord);
```

Now I want to re-write the route with some middleware. I know how to do this route by route, for example the first route would be:

```
app.get('/word/:id', connect.ensureLoggedIn('/auth/facebook'), word.getWord);
```

But can I apply the same middleware to all 3 routes at once?

Comment: `app.use(midlewareFn)` before your routes declarations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// -- @section router middleware
router.use(function (req, res, next) {

  /* your code here */

  next();
});

// -- @section routes
router.get('/users', function (req, res) {
  //res.render('users')
});

router.post('/users', function (req, res) {

});
```